# How can I remove the empty element that is automatically being appended to a select tag's model in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have a select tag with an ng-model and ng-options on it. On a click of another button i need to clear the ng-options array and populate it with another set of values and set the first element of the array to the ng-model.

But, when I clear the ng-options array, an empty value is automatically being appended which is deafultly done by angularjs. However even after populating the array with new values and reassigning the ng model, the select shows the empty element.

```
<select class="leversDropdown"  data-ng-model="currentLever" ng-options=" data.description for data in levers" data-ng-change="SelectLever(currentLever)"></select>

    var leversDataAppend = function (data) {

       $scope.levers = [];
       for (i = 0; i < data.d[0].length; i++) {
            $scope.leverDropDownObject = {
                descriptionId: data.d[0][i].DescriptionID,
                description: data.d[0][i].Description,
                targetDetailedData: []
            }
            $scope.levers.push($scope.leverDropDownObject);
        }

        if ($scope.levers.length != 0) {
            $scope.currentLever = $scope.levers[0];
         }

      }
```

Comment: After refreshing could you please try `$apply`, which will update the view also.

Comment: This should work without the blank value since you are assigning the model to the first element. Can you reproduce in plunker?

Comment: @Rajeshwar Apply doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: Are u getting any errors on the console while performing the operation?

Comment: Yes. We are getting that $digest already in progress